# Javascript: mutationobserver is not alerting message

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am trying to detect the CSS property changes in an element. I searched online and found `MutationObserver` javascript API. but in my test script it is not working as expected( it's not alerting the property name and property value).

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("hideit");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    alert('mutation.type = ' + mutation.type);

  });

});
observer.observe(foo);
observer.disconnect();

$(function() {
  $("#clickhere").on("click", function() {
    $("#hideit").slideToggle('fase');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="clickhere">click to toggel</div>
  <div id="hideit" style="display:none;">this is the content of the hide/show toggle</div>

</body>
```

and it shows a javascript error

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 6):

There're 2 problems in your code:

1. usage of `observer.observe` is incorrect. It should take 2 params: Node and [MutationObserverInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit). See the correct API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).
2. Do not call `observer.disconnect();` immediately after `observe`. [Disconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#disconnect()) stops observing.

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/tuxipixofi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is being executed before the DOM is actually being loaded... For that reason, you're passing a null/undefined value to the `observe` method.

Wrap your code inside:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
....
})
```

Also calling disconnect will prevent it from receiving any event. So you shouldn't call `disconnect` right after calling `observe`. And you're missing a parameter to the `observe` call.

Check here for a working exemple:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage